# Git keep file in sync task between 2 repos in Azure DevOps

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have file that I need to keep in sync between 2 repos (2 different organizations)

1. https://org1@dev.azure.com/org1/XProject/_git/MyRepoX
2. https://org2@dev.azure.com/org2/YProject/_git/MyRepoY

Both RepoX and RepoY have a file in common "FileA"  (to keep in sync)

When a change occurs FileA -Trigger pipeline and "Merge" MyRepoX/FileA into MyRepoY/FileA

I have done the following:

- Created a PAT token from Org1
- Created a PAT token from Org2
- Created pipeline with cmdline script
- In the script I did:

  - git clone https://@dev.azure.com/org1/XProject/_git/MyRepoX
  - git merge https://@dev.azure.com/org1/YProject/_git/MyRepoY

Error "Nothing to merge".

I am a "git novice" what command do I need to do to keep a file in sync between repos?

Comment: Why not put the file in a package and have your CI/CD process consume the package?

Comment: @DanielMann Could you expand a bit more I did not think of it.The all thing must happen on commit of a change of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just do the merge like you did because it's 2 different repositories, also,  do you really want to merge the whole repo? you need only one file to sync.

You can make it happen with this logic:

- Clone the second repo
- Copy `FileA` from repo 1 to repo 2
- Commit & Push

I wrote a small PowerShell script that works:

```
cd $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
git clone https://PAT-HERE@dev.azure.com/{organzition}/{project}/_git/{repo-name}
cd {repo-name}
git checkout branch-name # if the synced file not in master
# Assuming the synced file name is "test.txt" and he exists in the folder "common"
Copy-Item $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\common\test.txt $(Agnet.BuildDirectory)\{repo-name}\common -Force
# If you use Hosted agent you need to configure the email & address
git config --globa user.email "Build@AzureDevOps.com" 
git config --global user.name "Azure DevOps Build"
git add common/test.txt
git commit -m "Sync test.txt"
git push
```

Now create 2 pipelines, in each pipelines do the trigger only the common file you want to sync:

[image]

With the above script:

[image]

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Let me understand what you did. I only need to sync one file NOT the all repo.

Comment: @developer9969 Yea, in my example I sync only one file :)

Comment: @Abramczyk. Just tried .grr  "Get error "The term 'Agent.BuildDirectory' is not recognized as the name" (I should not be getting this error)
I am using a release pipeline agent "Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019".mmm

Comment: @developer9969 The variable is for build pipeline, not for Release, why do you use release pipeline?

Comment: @Abramczyk .Sorry switched to build and getting further... 
I omitted git checkout branch-name as its master 
Is git config for email and user (required) i guess is the "target repo.correct?.


Get error not sure why.
 I  error + git commit -m "Sync test.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: @developer9969 I'm sorry I didn't understand the error... can you edit your question with exactly what did you try and what the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195431/discussion-between-developer9969-and-shayki-abramczyk).